# Match close element pairs from two numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy

I have two numpy arrays, I would like to have a one-to-one mapping between the two arrays so that elements that are closest to each other get mapped to each other. I have written the following script that basically does that, but I do not like that the mapping is not deterministically unique, like for some configurations It might print the same index twice.

```
array1 = np.array([[324, 274], [542,274], [99,275]])
array2 = np.array([[571, 266], [67, 265], [320, 266]])

for i in range(len(array1)):
    print(np.argmin(np.linalg.norm(array2 - array1[i], axis=1)))
```

I am not yet sure how specifying the axis actually working in this context, although I know that choosing axis=0 means taking it by rows, and axis=1 means taking this it by columns, but since it is 2D array not sure how to interpret that.

I also thought about KD-Trees but I am not sure If using them would be the appropriate choice, and not an overkill for this task.

I would like to note, that when I refer to the closest element, I mean in both dimensions so It is essentially euclidean distance, I would really appreciate it also if someone could highlight on axis=1 and axis=0 in the code I provided, as well as getting the closest element considering only one axis. zipping them as well all in one liner, without loops if possible.

Comment: You'll have to add some more clarity about the logic that you'd like to use. One simple approach would be to sort each array and zip them together. This guarantees lowest in array1 <-> lowest in array2, etc. However, you might prefer to choose elements which are very close to each other, and pair the outliers together. Ex: `array1 = [0, 10, 11], array2 = [11, 12, 20] -> [(11, 11), (10, 12), (0, 20)]` Actually, it would be very helpful if you show the ideal output for your given dataset.

Comment: Basically what I want is the one that is closer in both x and y at once, so It is essentially the euclidian distance, but I want to do it know how to do that in all different ways if possible

Comment: cdist can give you distance between all pairs https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html

Comment: "I do not like that the mapping is not deterministically unique," - this is not something you can avoid with an arbitrary list of points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import linear_sum_assignment

array1 = np.array([[324, 274], [542, 274], [99, 275]])
array2 = np.array([[571, 266], [67, 265], [320, 266]])

# Calculate the distance matrix between each pair of points
distance_matrix = np.linalg.norm(array1[:, np.newaxis, :] - array2[np.newaxis, :, :], axis=2)

# Solve the assignment problem
row_ind, col_ind = linear_sum_assignment(distance_matrix)

# Print the results
for i, j in zip(row_ind, col_ind):
    print(f"Point {i} in array1 is mapped to point {j} in array2")
```

Comment: Thank you very much, May I ask for your kind elaboration, on how to solve the linear_sum_assignment problem if the task was to match the smallest from the first with the largest from the second?